# urllib3 PoolManager.request blocks forever when run from inside a running Thread in Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib3

I have a fairly simple REST request that I want to make during some asynchronous processing that happens inside a Flask application.  I took the naive approach of doing this async processing by just starting a Thread and letting the work get done inside the Thread, e.g.:

```
t = Thread(target=_do_stuff, daemon=True)
t.start()

def _do_stuff():
    # stuff happens here.
```

The problem I am having is that when I make a call to a `urllib3.PoolManager`'s `.request` method from somewhere inside the call stack of _do_stuff(), it eventually blocks forever when it gets to the line `conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)` in connectionpool.py.  If a timeout is specified, it is ignored.

If I run the same code but do it *outside* the thread (ie, run it synchronously), then it executes immediately and everything works as expected.

I'm sure there must be something I'm missing about threading in Python 3 or with respect to urllib3, but my questions are:

1. What am I missing, and,
2. What are my options for doing this in a way that will work?

Comment: cannot reproduce your issue, could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: the issue you've described sounds like a deadlock, while there is lock used in PoolManager, I need to reproduce the issue first.

Comment: I'm working on just that. Because of the number of moving parts it is proving to be complicated.

Comment: While trying to distill down the problem to its simplest form, I've also observed that inside a Flask endpoint, merely spawning a thread and having that thread do a time.sleep(1) will also block forever (ie, it never makes it to the statement following the sleep).  The urllib3 request will also succeed if its thread is started *first*, before other work happens in the endpoint and the endpoint returns.

Comment: Another observation: taking signals and call decorators out of the picture, merely starting a thread inside a Flask endpoint to make the HTTP request also locks up, but ONLY if it's the last thing the endpoint does.  If the thread starts first, it will execute successfully.  So I suspect some kind of race/resource contention with something inside Flask.

Comment: Flask is known to work with threads.